# can't install kivy pycharm

Tags: python, kivy, installation

i did everything the kivy website asked me to do all the pip installs and stuff, my setuptool is up to date but i'm still getting the
 `ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output`.
watched some videos and looked up other posts but i still cannot download it with project interpreter

note: i downloaded kivy_venv using the terminal but the project interpreter still gives me the above error. and kivy_venv module does not do anything...

Comment: What py version are you running, and what are all the commands you ran?
Also, Check the logs for full command output. :)

Comment: Also also, this guy has pretty much every binary installer you could ever need. Kivy is on this page, it seems.
https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: Also also also, before someone asks - 
https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#installing-from-wheels